# Cell References in React Material UI Table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am learning React and want to make a editable table where the $/Unit cell changes with Price and Units cells.

I struggle to find a way to access other cell values. Is it a possible to do it with Material UI table?

[image]
CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-meadow-486z9

```
import React from "react";
import MaterialTable from "material-table";

export default function CustomEditComponent(props) {
  const { useState } = React;

  const [columns, setColumns] = useState([
    {
      title: "Product",
      field: "product"
    },
    {
      title: "Price",
      field: "price"
    },
    {
      title: "Units",
      field: "pack"
    },
    {
      title: "$/Unit",
      field: "unitPrice",
      editComponent: props => (
        <input
          type="number"
          value={props.value} //how to access other cell values?
          onChange={e => props.onChange(e.target.value)}
        />
      )
    }
  ]);

  const [data, setData] = useState([
    { product: "Coke", price: 12, pack: 12, unitPrice: 1 },
    { product: "Beer", price: 12, pack: 6, unitPrice: 2 }
  ]);

  return (
    <MaterialTable
      title="Custom Edit Component Preview"
      columns={columns}
      data={data}
      editable={{
        onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) =>
          new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              const dataUpdate = [...data];
              const index = oldData.tableData.id;
              dataUpdate[index] = newData;
              setData([...dataUpdate]);

              resolve();
            }, 1000);
          })
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside onRowUpdate you can manipulate your newData values and then pass the modified values to setData func. A simple way to do it could be:

```
onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) =>
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          const dataUpdate = [...data];
          const index = oldData.tableData.id;
          newData["unitPrice"] = newData["price"] / newData["pack"];
          dataUpdate[index] = newData;
          setData([...dataUpdate]);

          resolve();
        }, 1000);
      })
```

Also if you want to restrict that field from being modified, you can set the 'editable' attribute at the column definition to 'never'. `editable: "never",`

Link to [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-morning-7182u?file=/src/App.js:430-449).