# Material-table conditional column edit value

Tags: material-table

I have two columns in my **material-table**.

1. Product
2. Product price

On first column (product) value change, I want to make second column value the price of product.
Price column is not editable. It is decided on what product I choose (1st column)

Columns:

```
const columns = [
  {
    title: 'Product',
    field: 'product',
    editComponent: props => {
      return (
        <Autocompleter
          onChange={props.onChange}
        />
      );
    },
  },
  {
    title: 'Price',
    field: 'price',
    editable: 'never'
  }
};
```

Comment: Try checking this answer, there is also a sandbox with an example of what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62377337/10569220

Comment: @NicoE In this example the value of non-editable column changes only after `onRowUpdate`. 
Is it possible to change the value on first column value change? (Before submitting the whole row to update it)